# Change default save folder

Tags: dm-script

I would like to know if it is possible to change the default folder where the images are saved. My data should be stored on the D:\work folder instead of the default folder. Is it possible to do this on the preferences of DM or by script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving behavior is different for the various GMS versions, but the 'default' folder is generally handled by Windows, not DigitalMicrograph, which limits the control over it.

> The **Save** / **Save As** functionality generally utilizes the *last opened/saved* folder as the starting default.

If you are using the **Saved Numbered** functionality (which is also used in any of the auto-save routines), then you can specify the folder directly.

[image]

If this isn't satisfying your needs, another option is to come up with your own little saving-script which you can customize to your need. That script could either be installed as a Menu-entry (plus a short-key to trigger it with, if you want), or it could launch a dialog/palette which remains open.

Comment: An example of a custom-saving plugin/script can f.e. be found on this site: Look for [QuickSave Tool](http://dmscript.tavernmaker.de/).

Comment: Thanks. In my case, when I want to save a file with control-S, just after lauching DM, the default directory is the Windows directory. This is what I wanted to change.

Comment: @EricLeroy Interesting. What GMS version? I have just tested GMS 3.2.2. and the directory on first CTRL+S is the one which DM saved to successfully last (before shut-down of DM). However, it might be that saving files with *other applications* changes this, as it is a windows-thing. (Tested on win7) In any case, I would not know how to change that folder - except by successfully saving a file. (A startup-script that saves and deletes a dummy file might work...)

Comment: GMS 2.32 32 bits on Windows 7 32bits

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that since **GMS 3.2** the following script does exactly what you want:

```
string path = "C:\\Temp\Num" + trunc(Random()*100)  // Just some new path
string pathID = "open_save"

number doCreate = 1 // Create if it does not exist
SetApplicationDirectory(pathID , doCreate, path )
Result( "\n Set default path to:" + path )
Result( "\n Path is:" + GetApplicationDirectory(pathID,doCreate) )
```

Sadly, setting the "open_save" folder is **not supported in GMS 2.x**, though.